# Which countries can I visit on an expired US visa but valid status in USA?

Tags: countries, h1b-visas

Which countries can I visit if my H-1B has expired but I am still on valid status in the USA by way of extensions to the expired H-1B?

I have heard that visiting Puerto Rico and Mexico isn't a problem. And there are many cases where an extension to an H1B is filed and the I-94 has expired.

Can a person travel to Canada and Mexico and come back using "Automatic Revalidation"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puerto Rico is not a country.  It is a US territory.  Travel between the mainland US and Puerto Rico is not subject to border controls.  It is a domestic flight like any other.  So, yes, you can visit Puerto Rico just as you can visit California and New York.

You can visit Mexico and Canada under the "automatic revalidation" scheme.  You may not stay for longer than 30 days; if you do, you will need to apply for a new visa.

You will also be ineligible for automatic revalidation if "any of the following situations exists":

- You have applied for a new visa which has not yet been issued;
- You have applied for a new visa and were denied;
- You have traveled to a country other than Canada or Mexico
- You are a national of a State Sponsor of Terrorism designated country, including Iran, Syria, and Sudan.  This list can change, so check before you leave.

Source: http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/automatic-revalidation.html

There are additional revalidation provisions for student visitors, but I have omitted these because they do not apply to you.

Comment: @Aspirant  Remember to bring your I-94 with you.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: Thanks for that piece of information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is that in fact important, given that the I-94 is now a print-it-yourself record in a government database?

Comment: @phoog The airline needs to see it so that they know he is in status and will not refuse boarding.

Comment: @MichaelHampton of course.  I was imagining a land crossing for some reason.  Well, I know the reason: all but one of my trips to Canada have been by land or ferry.

Comment: There are many cases where an extension to an H1B is filed and the I-94 has expired. Can a person travel to Canada and Mexico and come back using "Automatic Revalidation"?

Comment: @Aspirant according to the information on the CBP website, a valid I-94 is required, so no. The person would have to wait until the H-1B extension isapproved, whereupon a new I-94 will be issued.